# APIRTC Leaving Conversation does not allow Re-Enter

Tags: javascript, cordova, voip

In Cordova using https://cloud.apizee.com/apiRTC/apiRTC-latest.min.js

Leaving a conversation appears to work, until you try and rejoin it.  Then you get this error.
joinSession: session already set

To join the code is

```
conversation.join().then...;
```

When leaving the steps we are following are:

```
conversation.unpublish(localStream)
localStream.release();
conversation.destroy();
conversation.leave();
conversation = null;
localStream = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

To leave a conversation, just call leave() but not destroy(), otherwise you cannot join back.

My code :

```
leave(): void {
  if (this.conversation) {
    this.conversation.leave()
      .then(() => {
        this.joined = false;
        console.info('Conversation left');
        // do not destroy otherwise you cannot join back !
        // this.conversation.destroy();
        // this.conversation = null;
      })
      .catch(err => { console.error('Conversation leave error', err); });
  }
}
```